# Getting selected value from drop down in JS function

Tags: javascript, jsp, dropdown

I am trying to get the selected value from drop down from JSP. But I am not able to get the values. Can you please help me here. Below is the code snippet.

```
function showScreen()
{
    var frm_name = "jpFrm";
    var ele1 = document.getElementById("ele1");
    var ele2 = document.getElementById("ele2");
    alert("1st : " + ele1.value);
    alert("2nd : " + ele2.value);

    if(ele1.value != "" && ele2.value != "" )
    {
        alert("Form is going to submit");
        frm_name.submit();
        alert("Form Submited");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some html?

Comment: when and how is this function being called ? add some html may be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I got the solution from my friend. The issue is with my browser. I have added below meta tags in my code and then my code started working as expected.

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your html is. But you can get value and text of selected item from dropdown by the below snippet:

```
   <select id="ddlCar">
          <option value="1">Car1</option>
          <option value="2" selected="selected">Car2</option>
          <option value="3">Car3</option>
        </select>

       function getDDl(){
        var ele = document.getElementById("ddlCar");
        var carValue= ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;
        var cartext= ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you have mentioned but didn't get the value.

Comment: can you post that what are you doing and how you are doing?

Comment: I can't post the actual code since it is related to production. What I am doing is, I am writing a JSP using JSPWritter and inside which I have these drop downs. And calling above function in onChange of the dropdown.